# filenames with ' in, (we're) is messing with my script

Tags: bash, shell-script, filenames, nemo

I have a script that first move the selected files into a temp directory,scans the directory, takes the largest file and create a new directory with that name, and moving all files to the newly created directory.

but it's crashing when bumping into directories or files containing the ' character, for example the word **we're**
I think it can have something to do with the jfilenameall isn't "quoted" right, and I have tested a few ways, but haven't got it to work.

anybody that knows what I'm doing wrong?

*Worth mention* is that I'm running this script Via nemo action, so the following command line is executed:
`script.sh "path/filename1.txt" "path/filename2.txt"`  ..and so on depending on how many files that was selected in the gui

```
jdir2="$1"
jdirfirst="${jdir2%/*}"
jdir="$jdirfirst"/
jdir0="$jdirfirst"
tmpdir="$jdir0/tmp.tmp3"
mkdir "$tmpdir"
mv "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$tmpdir"/
                
 jfilenameall=$(basename $(find $tmpdir -maxdepth 1 -type f  -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'))
jfilename="${jfilenameall::-4}"
jfilenameextension="$(echo -n $jfilenameall | tail -c 3)"
jfilename=${jdirlast::-4}    
mkdir "$jdir0/$jfilename"
mv "$jdir0/tmp.tmp3/"* "$jdir0/$jfilename/"
```

Comment: quote your `$(find ...)` part like this `jfilenameall=$(basename "$(find ... )")`. Does that help? Anyways, you're command will also have problems with spaces in filenames like in "we are" to stay with your example ;-)

Comment: Note that your script does not _copy_ the files you give it, it _moves_ them.

Comment: Also, what operating system are you using? Are you on Linux? Can we assume GNU tools?

Comment: @terdon yes, Linux, move, not copy, my bad  ..

Comment: @pLumo was you referring the find command or some other issues?

Comment: Why `jfilenameextension="$(echo -n $jfilenameall | tail -c 3)"` when you've been using `jfilename=${jdirlast::-4}` constructs elsewhere? Better would (probably) be `jfilenameextension="${jfilenameall##*.}"`. Bear in mind both your original and my suggested replacement assume there is an extension

Comment: Double-quote the variables when you use them. Everywhere.`find "$tmpdir"...` and `echo -n "$jfilenameall" | tail -c 3`

Comment: @roamina I'm using different approaches due to my "stupidity", I try to not mess with what I don't understand...

Comment: @roamina I thought " did close the quote, so this line: `jfilenameextension="$(echo -n "$jfilenameall" | tail -c 3)"` would be interpreted as: `jfilenameextension=`"$(echo -n "`$jfilenameall`" | tail -c 3)"

Comment: JoBe, don't put yourself down. Stupidity is not lack of knowledge. Stupidity is refusing either to learn or apply knowlege when it has been offered or gained

Answer (score 1):

This will do what your question describes (I removed some of the steps you had since they didn't seem necessary). Note that it assumes you are using GNU tools. The main issue was that you weren't double quoting your variables and command substitutions. I also made this work for some weirder file names such as those containing newlines or those starting with `-`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

## You don't define $jdir0 in your script, so I am assuming you
## do so earlier. I'm setting it to '/tmp' here.
jdir0="/tmp"

## Create a temp dir in $jdir0
tmpdir=$(mktemp -dp "$jdir0")

## Move all arguments passed to the script to the tmp dir,
## this way you don't need to specify $1, $2 etc. The -- ensures
## this will work even if your file names start with '-'.
mv -- "$@" "$tmpdir"/


## Get the largest file's name. Assume GNU find; deal with arbitrary file names,
## including those with spaces, quotes, globbing characters or newlines
IFS= read -r -d '' jfilenameall < <(find "$tmpdir" -maxdepth 1 -type f \
                                        -printf '%s\t%p\0' | sort -zn |
                                        tail -zn1 | cut -f 2-)

## Assume GNU find; deal with arbitrary file names, including those with
## spaces, quotes, globbing characters or newlines
jfilenameall="$(basename "$jfilenameall")"

## Get the extension: whatever comes after the last . in the file name. You don't
## use this anywhere, but maybe you just don't show it. If the file has no extension,
## this variable will be set to the entire file name.
jfilenameextension="${jfilenameall##*.}"

## get the file name without the extension. Don't assume an extension will always be 3 chars
jfilename="${jfilenameall%.*}"

## You don't define $jdir0 in your script. I am assuming you do so earlier
mkdir -p "$jdir0/$jfilename"
mv -- "$tmpdir/"* "$jdir0/$jfilename/"

## remove the now empty tmp dir
rmdir "$tmpdir"
```

Comment: After defining `jfilenameextension` you should consider `[[ "$jfilenameextension" == "$jfilenameall" ]] && jfilenameextension=` to handle the case where there is no dot in the filename. You don't need a corresponding fix for `jfilename`.

Comment: @roaima ah yes, thanks. But I also have another issue with the null byte in the substitution. I'll fix both.

Comment: @roaima I fixed the other issue (I'd forgotten that bash complains about nulls in command substitutions) but on second thought, I think leaving `jfilenameextension` be the full name when there's no extension is fine. The variable isn't used anywhere, for one thing, I just included it because it was in the question.

Comment: @terdon `jdir2="$1"
jdirfirst="${jdir2%/*}"
jdir="$jdirfirst"/
jdir0="$jdirfirst"` is how I determine the jdir0, I'm running this script from gui,  so the script is executed as:   `script.sh "filename 1" "filename 2"` and so on..  the jfilenameextension is a leftover, and not used in this script

Comment: @JoBe that seems... overly complicated. But does the answer solve your issue? You can set `jdir0` as you wish. The main problem was the quoting.

Comment: @terdon I'm not so good at coding, so I'm trying to solve the issues with what I know and what I've done before, Instead of complicating it with #@\`s\`$# , which I don't understand, and thankfully there are nice users here that's helping if there are something I don't get to work , I'll test the script momentarily..

Comment: @JoBe don't worry, that's how we all learn! :)

Comment: @terdon it didn't actually work, something is of with the find statement,  I think, did you calculate with that the argument after the script contains multiple paths/names (or sometimes only one)?

Comment: @JoBe I don't know what you mean. When asking questions, please make sure to include all relevant information in the actual question so we can know what you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113022/discussion-between-jobe-and-terdon).